# Getting return value from switch case to function or method

Tags: java, android

```
         private final Handler mHandler = new Handler() {
                @Override
                public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
                    switch (msg.what) {

                        case Constants.MESSAGE_READ:
                             byte[] readBuf = (byte[]) msg.obj;

                    String Message = new String(readBuf, 0, msg.arg1);


                                }
                        break;

public void condition(){
//get Message
}
```

Hi How do I get/return the message in the switch case handler message to pass into the condition method/function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try implementing String Message="" in the top of your class and using it in the function ? it will be global .

Answer (score 1):

You can extend `Handler` create a class and save a field in it,then provide getter and setter method to visit data.

```
public static class MyHandler extends Handler{
    //add your field and getter/setter method
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        //visit your field
    }
}
```